# EC2 Ubuntu instance autocomplete shell commands

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-ec2

While using AWS "Session Manager" I can easily connect to the instance. I logged in as a "ssm-user" and for some reason **shell commands doesn't autocomplete**. For ex. cd folder/[TAB] doesn't work.

I can switch to SU and everything will be available. Or I can create another user where all the commands will work right away. The thing is, I want to have this avility right away on the "ssm-user".

UPDATE:
So running simply `bash` or `zsh` if it's installed will be enought to enter interactive shell. That's was embarasing reasy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what shell 'ssm-user' is using. Make sure it's one that actually supports tab completion (like bash or zsh).

Answer (score 3):

In your session manager preferences you can [specify the shell](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-preferences-shell-config.html) the you want to use. To use `bash` you can set it as follows:

[image]

Please note that you may need to **upgrade your SSM Agent** on the instance. If you have old version, the shell profiles may not work. This can be easily done using `AWS-UpdateSSMAgent` SSM Run Command.